# primeng multiselect precheck items

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using the multiselect module from `PrimeNG`.I am copying the following code from the documentation:

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'DataShit';
  cities1: SelectItem[];
  cities2: City[];
  selectedCities1: City[];
  selectedCities2: City[];

  constructor() {
    //SelectItem API with label-value pairs
    this.cities1 = [
      {label: 'New York', value: {id: 1, name: 'New York', code: 'NY'}},
      {label: 'Rome', value: {id: 2, name: 'Rome', code: 'RM'}},
      {label: 'London', value: {id: 3, name: 'London', code: 'LDN'}},
      {label: 'Istanbul', value: {id: 4, name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST'}},
      {label: 'Paris', value: {id: 5, name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS'}}
    ];

    //An array of cities
    this.cities2 = [
      {name: 'New York', code: 'NY'},
      {name: 'Rome', code: 'RM'},
      {name: 'London', code: 'LDN'},
      {name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST'},
      {name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS'}
    ];
  }
}
```

Now I am rendering the `cities2` using the following markup in my component.

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cities2" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities2" defaultLabel="Select your city">
  <ng-template let-city pTemplate="item">
    {{city.name}}
  </ng-template>
</p-multiSelect>
```

Now my question is: Can i precheck some of this checkboxes based on some conditions?(E.g.: cities that start with 'S' or a different filter)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can.

You need to bind your selected data with `[(ngModel)]="selectedCities2"`, this will allow you to show pre selected data filled in multiselect.

For example -

```
selectedCities2 = ['NY', 'RM'];
```

Comment: I cannot seem to be able to use it

Comment: Let's say I want to display New York and Rome checked and all the others unchecked.How can I achieve this

Comment: @ManosKounelakis I have given the same example

Comment: I am afraid It displays nothing

Comment: Try selecting two elements here and see functionalty part https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/multiselect

Comment: I have seen that page but found nothing that could help me

Comment: @ManosKounelakis Just create a stackblitz for the same , I'll update you there